# codeigniter, routes and languages

Tags: codeigniter

I want to make custom routing and I did it, I understand that using $route['blog'] = 'Main/blog'; for ie, we can forward this to corresponding controller and that is OK.
Now I want to make it more elegant / dynamic. So my idea is to try something like this:

```
$ci = & get_instance();
$ci->load->helper('language');
$route[$ci->lang->line('url_About_Me')] = 'Main/about/' . $ci->lang->line('ISO 639-1');
```

Because URL part of url_About_Me will be dynamically configured and can be any that users wants to be, and still controller function about will stay just as that (that is part of design).
Now this is throwing an error:

```
Message: Class 'CI_Controller' not found
```

So, does anyone know how to overcome this? And is there anywhere a diagram or some workflow where I can see what comes first and last in codeigniter from the moment URL is requested by user.

Thanks.

Comment: It's supposed to be `$ci =& get_instance();`

Comment: Yes, but it seems that controller is not reachable from routes, like they posted in their application workflow chart: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html